# When I do malloc(1), it allocates 8 spaces in a char*, and I have no idea why

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
int newSize = size + 1; //lets say size = 0
char * newArray = malloc(newSize * sizeof(char));
printf("%li", sizeof(newArray)); //Should be 1, prints 8
printf("%li", newSize * sizeof(char)); //Should be 1, prints 1
```

I have no clue why it's doing this, but I need newArray to have exactly newSize number of char spots. Any ideas?

Comment: `sizeof(newArray)` is the size of the pointer, not what it points to.

Comment: There's no way to find out the size of what a pointer points to.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? `malloc()` is guaranteed to allocate as much space as you request, unless it returns `NULL`.

Comment: It might allocate more, because all allocations need to be aligned for the largest datatype. But the excess space isn't detectable and shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because `newArray` is a pointer `sizeof(newArray)` gives you the size of the pointer, **not** the size of the buffer it points to.

When allocating memory you need to keep track of the size of that memory yourself as the language does not give you a way to find that out.

Comment: But is there a way to allocate exactly x characters worth of space instead of always 8, given that I know what x is?

Comment: @NikhilJindia What makes you think it allocated 8? That's not the amount of space that was allocated.

Comment: You are allocating 1 character. The 8 is the size of the variable `newArray`, which holds a pointer.

Comment: When I try to fwrite it to a file it prints the 4 characters it should print then 4 of "^@"

Comment: @NikhilJindia You *did* allocate 1 character in this case.  What you're trying to do to determine the size won't work as you expect.

Comment: @NikhilJindia don't use `sizeof(newArray)` when writing to the file, either. It's not meaningful at all.

Comment: @NikhilJindia Then you're not correctly keeping track of how many characters to print.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue, I used sizeof() for the fwrite, I think it's fixed now I'll check

Edit: It's working! Thanks so much! Totally brainfarted on the sizeof thing (still trying to learn this language lol)

Comment: There's no *portable* way, but some malloc implementations can tell you how much space was allocated (which might be more then requested)... glibc's [`malloc_usuable_size()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html) for example.

Comment: My prof isn't letting us use any libs other than stdlib stdio sys/time and sys/stat but it's working now